# Oracle update via join on text values for csv

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, join

Some background - I have an exported CSV dataset which will be imported/migrated into a new system. I don't have an identifying ID in this dataset as it's not needed in the new system but i now need to add some additional data into this CSV.

I've imported the CSV into an Oracle table and created 2 new columns - FieldLabelEDRN and ELEMENTID. I want to update those 2 columns with the relevant data from the original tables so i tried the following

```
UPDATE EDRN_NEW.DATADIC
SET FIELDLABELEDRN =
  (SELECT short_name
  FROM edrn.md$$_all_data_elements
  WHERE active_yn = 'YES'
  ORDER BY short_name
  ),
SET ELEMENTID =
  (SELECT element_id
  FROM edrn.md$$_all_data_elements
  WHERE active_yn = 'YES'
  ORDER BY short_name
  )
```

That produces an ora-00907 error and i know it's very basic. I'm struggling to think of a way to get the value i need. I had also tried to join the 2 tables together on the short_name = field label to just pull in the element_id as that's what i really need but i'm not very familiar with not being able to use a JOIN in an UPDATE with Oracle

Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You need some method of matching the new values to the rows they go in.

Comment: In addition to @GordonLinoff comment, your syntax is incorrect, `SET` should be used only once.

Comment: Unrelated, but, you can improve the performance by using only a single sub-select `set (FIELDLABELEDRN, ELEMENTID) = (select short_name, element_id from ...)` - the `order by` in the sub-select is useless however

Comment: Apologies, I realize my syntax is incorrect now. I'll try out the sub-select set, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle offers a short-hand for updating multiple columns.  However, you need some method of matching the rows in the staging table to the existing table.

The syntax looks like this:

```
UPDATE EDRN_NEW.DATADIC dd
    SET (FIELDLABELEDRN, ELEMENTID) =
         (SELECT short_name, element_id
          FROM edrn.md$$_all_data_elements ade
          WHERE active_yn = 'YES' AND
                ade.?? = dd.??
         );
```

But you need some sort of way of matching the rows, so you need to fill in the details in `ade.?? = dd.??`.

It is also possible that you are confusing `UPDATE` with `INSERT`.  Do you just want this?

```
INSERT INTO EDRN_NEW.DATADIC(FIELDLABELEDRN, ELEMENTID)
      SELECT short_name, element_id
      FROM edrn.md$$_all_data_elements ade
      WHERE active_yn = 'YES' ;
```

Comment: Always learning something new.. didn't know about this method , +1 .

Comment: I was hoping to be able to match on short_name = field_label but i can't do that because of "SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: I can however just use the insert and match the records up in excel so that works for me, thank you.